# How do I convert gyroscope values recorded via xamarin.essentials on Wear OS and Tizen to a mutual unit

Tags: wear-os, tizen, gyroscope, xamarin.essentials

I have implemented a simple sensor collector app in Xamarin.Forms using Xamarin.Essentials for Wear OS and Tizen.
I am using a Samsung Galaxy Active 2 and a Fossil Sport for data collection.

One thing I stumbled upon was that accelerometer and gyroscope data are recorded in different units accross both platforms.
For the accelerometer Wear OS is recording in the unit G, Tizen in meters per seconds square, so a conversion to a mutual unit is relatively simple.
However I could not figure out what units are used for the gyroscope on both devices.
Is there someone who could share some insight?

Thanks in advance and kind regards
Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer to these guides, according to this guide, Tizen uses Degrees/s and Android uses rad/s.

Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion
Tizen: https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/location-and-sensors/device-sensors?langredirect=1#gyro

Answer (score 0):

After consulting the emulators for Tizen and Android the solution became apparent.
Tizen is using the unit degrees/s while Wear OS is using rad/s.